# Does private IP of an AWS instance change while instance is running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 instances running and a web application in one of them (Say instance1) uses private IP of another instance (Say instance2) to call a service.

I restarted instance2(IP changes after restart) and restarted the web application on instance1 after adjusting the configurations accordingly, and application was up and running successfully.
But then suddenly it stopped responding after 2 hours and when I looked for the problem, I found that the private IP of the instance2 was again changed while it was running.

Has it happened with anyone else? If yes what's the solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean public IP address?  Private IP addresses don't change if you stop or restart an instance.  "A private IPv4 address remains associated with the network interface when the instance is stopped and restarted, and is released when the instance is terminated."  [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html)

Comment: Also, public IP also doesn't change if the instance is simply restarted (not stopped and then started, just restarted/rebooted).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **private IP address** of an Amazon EC2 instance will *never* change.

It will *not* change while an instance is **running**.

It will *not* change while an instance is **stopped**.

You cannot change a private IP address. (However, I think that if you assign *multiple* private IP addresses, you can add/remove the secondary addresses, but not the primary IP address.)

You cannot launch another instance with the same private IP address of another instance (in the same VPC), even if the other instance is stopped.

The above only applies to the **private** IP address, not the **public** IP address.

Answer (score 0):

In you case you need to keep your public address from changing after instance shutdown. Take a look on using `ElasticIP` [Using ElasiticIP with EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

Answer (score 0):

For those who love the main source:

> A private IPv4 address, regardless of whether it is a primary or secondary address, remains associated with the network interface when the instance is stopped and started, or hibernated and started, and is released when the instance is terminated.

Link to the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-private-addresses