# how to stop my public ip address from changing in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have one **ec2 instance** running on aws. I am stopping and starting it by using the Lambda expression at a specific time interval. Whenever (ec2) **instance** starts from stop mode. it's public IP changes every time due to this always I have to change my **Ip address** for a hosted website in domain registrar. How to stop this **IP** from changing or assign an unchangeable Ip address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An IP address of EC2 instance gets changed after the restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414302/an-ip-address-of-ec2-instance-gets-changed-after-the-restart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an [AWS Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) and attach to your instance.

> An Elastic IP address is a static IPv4 address designed for dynamic
>   cloud computing. An Elastic IP address is associated with your AWS
>   account. With an Elastic IP address, you can mask the failure of an
>   instance or software by rapidly remapping the address to another
>   instance in your account.

Here is the confirmation that elastic IP is not released when you stop an instance.

> When you stop a running instance, the following happens:
>
> The instance retains its associated Elastic IP addresses. You're
>   charged for any Elastic IP addresses associated with a stopped
>   instance. With EC2-Classic, an Elastic IP address is dissociated from
>   your instance when you stop it. For more information, see EC2-Classic.

Source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html